# sched_setaffinity fails after I've used cset shield

Tags: linux, performance, scheduler

I am using `cset shield` to create a *user* shield with a set of cpus

```
 cset shield --cpu 1,3,5,7 --kthread on
```

The idea behind this is to reserve these cpus for my application code, and push all other tasks plus the movable kernel threads onto the other cpus.

In my application I create 4 threads, and in the context of each thread, attempt to use `sched_setaffinity` to pin each thread onto one of the reserved cpus.

```
int cpuNum = 1; // each thread gets one of the cpus
pid_t threadId = static_cast<pid_t>(syscall(SYS_gettid));

cpu_set_t cpuSet;
CPU_ZERO(&cpuSet);
CPU_SET(cpuNum, &cpuSet);

if (sched_setaffinity(threadId, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuSet) == -1)
    perror("sched_setaffinity");
```

However, `sched_setaffinity` fails with `Invalid argument`

If I run my application using `cset shield --exec ./TestApp` then the pinning works

How come the naked `sched_setaffinity` call fails?

Comment: Can you provide the operating system version and distribution? Kernel version may also be helpful.

Comment: @ewwhite This is suse 11. Will get the rest of the info for you tomorrow.

Comment: Oh bummer... because RHEL had a bug tied to the `sched_setaffinity` interface for awhile. I'm not sure on SuSE.

Answer (score 2):

Your application code looks correct. Quickly, try this without `--kthread on` when you create your CPU shields. See if you get the same "Invalid argument" error. I'm wondering if there's an issue with the kernel threads.

Also, is this RHEL? What is the hardware setup (# of cores)? I've seen issues with the `sched_setaffinity` call on applications moved from Gentoo to Red Hat systems.

Comment: Sadly doesn't work without `--kthread on` either.

Comment: Hardware setup is: 2 sockets, 6 cores per socket, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5680  @ 3.33GHz, hyperthreading enabled (but I enforce that no hyperthread cores can be pinned to) 
socket 0: cpus: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11; hyperthread_cpus: 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23; socket 1:  cpus: 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10; hyperthread_cpus: 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22